# Calculate inverse of $Df=\begin{pmatrix} 3x^2-y^2&-2xy\\2xy&x^2-3y^2 \end{pmatrix}$ ? Using inverse Function Theorem to find local diffeomorphism of f

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, inverse-function-theorem

$f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2, (x,y)\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} x^3-xy^2\\x^2y-y^3 \end{pmatrix}$
Determine all points $ a \in \mathbb {R}^{2} $ for which open sets $ U, V \subset \mathbb {R}^{2} $ exist such that $f|_{U}: U \rightarrow V $ is a diffeomorphism. In this case, also determine $ D(f_{U}^{-1})(f(a) $.

What I use:

The Inverse Function Theorem $(*)$
$ f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n} $ be continuously differentiable. If $\det Df(a) \neq 0 $ then there exists an open set $ U $ with $a\in U$ and an open set $V$ with $f(a)\in V$ such that $ f: U \rightarrow V $ is a local $C^1$-diffeomorphism.

So there exists a inverse $ f^{-1}: V \to U $ which is differentiable for all $y \in V $.

Then $Df^{-1}(y)=[Df(f^{-1}(y))]^{-1} $.

Set $a=f^{-1}(y)$ then $Df^{-1}(y)=[Df(a)]^{-1} $

Progress:

$f$ is continuously partially differentiable, so $f$ is differentiable.

$Df((x,y))=\begin{pmatrix} 3x^2-y^2&-2xy\\2xy&x^2-3y^2 \end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow$  $Df$ is continuous, so $f$ is continuously differentiable.

$\det \begin{pmatrix} 3x^2-y^2&-2xy\\2xy&x^2-3y^2 \end{pmatrix}=\det Df((x,y))=3x^4-6x^2y^2+3y^4=3(x^4+y^4)-6x^2y^2=0\Rightarrow 3(x^4+y^4)=6x^2y^2$

Set $x^2=u\, , y^2=v$:

$$3(x^4+y^4)= 6x^2y^2\Leftrightarrow u^2+v^2=2uv \Leftrightarrow 0=u^2-2uv+v^2=(u-v)^2\Leftrightarrow u=v \Leftrightarrow x^2=y^2 \Leftrightarrow |x|=|y|$$

So $\det Df((x,y))=3(x^4+y^4)-6x^2y^2\neq 0$ and therefore invertable if $|x|\neq |y|$.

So for every $a\in U':=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|\, |x|\neq |y|\}$ there exists an open set $ U $ with $a\in U$ and an open set $V$ with $f(a)\in V$ such that $ f: U \rightarrow V $ is a local $C^1$-diffeomorphism $(*)$.
So there exists a continuous differentiable inverse $ f^{-1}: V \to U $ .

Now I need to calculate $Df^{-1}(y)=[Df(a)]^{-1} $

How do i find the inverse of $Df((x,y))=\begin{pmatrix} 3x^2-y^2&-2xy\\2xy&x^2-3y^2 \end{pmatrix}$ with $|x|\neq |y|$? Gauss–Jordan elimination didn't work.

Comment: The inverse of $\left( \matrix{a & b \\ c& d} \right )\in M_2(\Bbb R)$ s.t. $ad-bc\ne0$ is $ \frac{1}{ad-bc}\left( \matrix{d & -b \\ -c& a} \right )$.

Comment: Thank you so much! $Df^{-1}(f(a))=\begin{pmatrix}x^2-3y^2 &2xy\\-2xy& 3x^2-y^2\end{pmatrix}$. Did I use the theorem correctly?

Comment: No, you forgot to divide by $ad-bc.$

Comment: $Df^{-1}(f(a))=\frac{1}{3(x^4+y^4)-6x^2y^2}\begin{pmatrix}x^2-3y^2 &2xy\\-2xy& 3x^2-y^2\end{pmatrix}$ And did I apply the inverse function theorem correctly?

Comment: Yes ok now. You could have solved $\det\dots=0$ more quickly by noticing immediately that $\det\dots=3(x^2-y^2)^2.$ If I understand the question correctly, you are also asked to show that if $|x|=|y|$ then $f$ is *not* a diffeo between some open neighborhoods of $a$ and $f(a).$ But this might be too difficult.